# C++ constructor init multiple members

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Given this class:

```
void calculate( int*, int* );

struct A{
    int p;
    int q;
    A() { calculate( &p, &q ); }
};
```

I want to make the members `p` and `q` constant:

```
struct A{
    const int p;
    const int q;
    // constructor???
};
```

The question is, how to I initialize those values?  I'd like to call `calculate`, or maybe some kind of proxy function, from within the constructor, but how can I do it in a way to initialize both values at a time?  One obvious idea would be a wrapper for the constructor:

```
A create_A(){
    int p0;
    int q0;
    calculate( &p0, &q0 );
    return A{ p0, q0 };
}
```

But this leaves me without an appropriate default constructor.  Very inconvenient.  Is there a way to accomplish this with a default constructor?

Just for fun, I actually found this, which does what I need but isn't really a viable option because it's not thread-safe:

```
int foo( bool b )
{
    static int p;
    static int q;
    if( b ){
        calculate( &p, &q );
        return p;
    } else {
        return q;
    }
}

struct A{
    const int p;
    const int q;
    A() : p( foo( true ) ), q( foo( false ) ){}
};
```

**EDIT** Many people complained about me using `const` members.  But this question is interesting beyond const-members, in my specific use-case `p` and `q` are not `int` but some class-type without a default constructor, so I need to use the member initialization syntax even if they are not const.  Oh, and of course const-members do have advantages:  faster debug-mode, fewer abstraction layers, less complexity, more compiler enforced invariants.

Comment: `const` members are a bad idea. This is just one of the MANY headaches you'll run into. Better to simply only expose `const` accessors.

Comment: @DeadMG The only other problem coming to my mind would be a missing assignment operator, which I can live without.  Can you think of any other issues I should expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a struct from your helper function, and delegate construction to another constructor, like this:

```
#include <utility>
std::pair<int,int> calculate();

struct A{
    const int p;
    const int q;
    A() : A(calculate()) {}
private:
    A(std::pair<int,int> a) : p(a.first), q(a.second) {}
};
```

Delegating constructors are in the standard since C++11, though they worked before in many compilers, as they were a semantically undefined construct.

Still, this disables the assignment-operator. Are you sure inline `const`-qualified accessors are not a better idea? They have no runtime-overhead.

Comment: const-qualified accessors do have a runtime-overhead in debug mode, which is what I use most of the time.  And they have an overhead in overall code size.

Comment: Hm, debug mode without optimisations, maybe. But that's not the mode where you measure, is it? Anyway, that goes for the standard-library, too, then.

Comment: I just hate it when I have to wait *forever* for the debugger to reach a certain position.  And I prefer a shallow stack over a deeply nested one.  Doesn't everyone?